# Program Not Responding after clean compile?

Tags: haxe

I've had to move my stuff from a failing hard drive, so I've had to set up and reinstall everything again. And I've run into a couple problems.

So I've got two errors here. The first error that I get is when I open flashdevelop to begin working. I get the error of:

```
Can't Find Haxelib.exe
```

And of course, I've installed haxe and haxelib and everything else that's needed pre-setup. However, when I run, the flash and html5 targets work fine regardless. I don't know why that error shows up. Any ideas?

My second problem is that I've installed the necessary stuff for the windows runtime. However, when I try to run the exe in or outside of flashdevelop, the program freezes and gives me the:

```
    This program is not responding.
```

error that you sometimes see when you crash a program. However, I have my neko stuff set up and it compiles fine, it just crashes on start. I have the background set to neko. I have just a sample hello world FlxText object like this:

```
    hello = new FlxText(0, 0, 100, "Hello World!");
    #if neko
    hello.color =  0xffffff;
    #else
    hello.color = 0xffffffff;
    #end
    add(hello);
```

Any idea what could be causing the start crashes? It also has me wondering if the two aren't related some how.

Thanks in advance!

Using windows 8, haxe, haxeflixel, windows & neko runtimes.

Answer (score 2):

I had this posted on another forum. The not responding error is fixed easily by adding:

```
<window allow-shaders="false"/>
```

In the projects xml file. The haxelib error still shows but it may be a non issue.

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

1. Make sure you use `Haxe 3` and `OpenFL` (I think there is no sense of using `Haxe 2` or `NME`).
2. Check if `Haxe` on *PATH* is `Haxe 3` and check that `OpenFL` work fine. (Just open *"cmd"* and type *"haxe"* there to see version of `Haxe` available and type *"openfl"* there to test if it works, also check *"haxelib"*)
3. Check `FlashDevelop Haxe SDK`
4. Trace your *haxelibs* here(use *haxelib list* in cmd)
5. `This program is not responding.`
   This may mean, that you don't have some .dll in bin folder.(Depending on what you use in your project).
   Or this may be connected somehow with your GPU drivers. Or it can be anything other. To get more info about that crash, try compiling to `neko`, and print output here.
6. Make sure you have latest *haxelibs* installed (`haxelib upgrade` and `haxelib selfupdate`)
7. To help you I need more info, print `FlashDevelop` output here.